# I runned a react native app in different devices. But I got a different result

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I runned a react native app in different devices.A device is iOS 9 and another is iOS 10. The device iOS 9 will encounter a error that could not connect to development server.The device iOS 10 can run successfully.I use react native 0.4.1. I will show you more informations if you need. I don't know what should I show.And you can tell me some ideas if you know some possible reason

Answer (score 0):

I believe all the devices must be connected to the same Apple Developer account. Check if both of your devices have the same Apple ID and try to run them through Xcode.

Also make sure you follow all the steps in these guides

[Running On Device](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html)

[Launching Your App on Devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH27-SW4)

If it doesn't work but you are still able to install the app, try to run the app with Wi-Fi while **being on the same network as your mac**, [here is the guide on how to do that](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#method-2-connect-via-wi-fi)

Cheers!